# How to populate Gmarker dynamically on Gmaps using ZK Framework

Tags: java, mvvm, google-maps-api-3, zk

I need help to populate Gmarker dynamically by data lng and lat from my database and showing in my ZK application, i am using Gmaps v.3.0.4

I have adding the marker inside the zul file and try to use forEach but only one marker is showed.

```
<gmaps version="3." id="gmaps" width="100%" showZoomCtrl="true" lat="@bind(vm.lat)" lng="@bind(vm.lng)" height="500px"  protocol="https" >
    <gmarker forEach="@load(areaList)" lat="@bind(each.lat)" lng="@bind(each.lng)" open="true">
    </gmarker>
</gmaps>`
```

The marker should be show as much as possible.

this is my complete code [ZUl file](https://pastebin.com/Z86WHQEp) and [ViewmModel](https://pastebin.com/4MTiST7P)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<gmaps version="3." id="gmaps" width="100%" showZoomCtrl="true" lat="@bind(vm.lat)" lng="@bind(vm.lng)" height="500px"  protocol="https" children="@load(vm.areaList)">
    <template name="children">
        <gmarker lat="@load(each.lat)" lng="@load(each.lng)" open="true" />
    </template>
</gmaps>
```

I haven't tested it but hopefully it helps.

Comment: I have tried as you suggested,but still no marker is showed

Comment: Failed to notice that you had `children="@load(areaList)"`. It should be `children="@load(vm.areaList)"`. I have edited my answer to include the change.

Comment: Thank you for answer i see the children should be `children="@load('vm.areaList)"`, but the problem is because the order lat and lng is reversed in my database, thanks now is working fine